Did the Aseres HaShevatim find out about the Churban?
Does anyone discuss whether the Aseres HaShevatim ever found out, in their exile, what fate befell Yehuda, and in particular, about the Churban?
(The question is inspired by the imagined dialog between אָהֳלָה and אָהֳלִיבָה in Kinnos.)

Bear in mind that many of them were brought back by Yirmiyahu some 30 years before the Churban (Megillah 14b, Erchin 33a). So you might want to clarify that the question is about those who remained behind.
